# Is there a way to connect to Magento Database from c# application?

Tags: c#, magento

I would like to build an application to access(read/write) magento database using c#. I am wondering is there any way to connect from an custom application? If yes, which would be the best? Please suggest me as I am new to Magento, Thanks.

Comment: You're a c# developer?

Comment: Then you can't go past using LINQPad to access your Magento database. I use it for so many database maintenance tasks. I'm happy to discuss with you if you like. Perhaps add my used id to Skype if you'd like to chat.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah sure, can I have your user Id? and thanks for your offer.

Comment: My Skype id is my SO id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using magento API, below code might help you;

```
using Magento_Import.MagentoAPI;

namespace Magento_Import
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient handler = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string session = handler.login("username", "password");

            catalogProductEntity[] products;
            handler.catalogProductList(out products, session, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (C#, VB.NET, F#) every day to connect to my Magento database via SSH tunneling.

There is a MySQL connection provider which allows you to effectively use LINQ to SQL with a Magento database.

I'm then able to run queries, such as this directly from LINQPad:

```
var items =
    from o in sales_flat_order
    where o.created_at > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100)
    join i in sales_flat_order_item on o.entity_id equals i.order_id
    where i.sku.Contains(sku)
    join p in sales_flat_order_payment on o.entity_id equals p.parent_id
    orderby o.created_at descending
    select new
    {
        timestamp = o.created_at,
        order = o.increment_id,
        i.sku,
        i.name,
        qty = i.qty_ordered,
        o.status,
        p.method,
        i.row_total_incl_tax,
    };
```

The tooling then lets you see the actual query/ies sent to the DB.

```
SELECT t0.created_at, t0.increment_id, t1.sku, t1.name, t1.qty_ordered, t0.status, t2.method, t3.qty, t1.row_total_incl_tax
FROM sales_flat_order AS t0
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.order_id)
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_payment AS t2
  ON (t0.entity_id = t2.parent_id)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t4.sku, t5.qty
  FROM catalog_product_entity AS t4
  INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS t5
    ON (t4.entity_id = t5.product_id)
  WHERE (t4.sku LIKE CONCAT('%',@p0,'%'))
  ) AS t3
  ON (t1.sku = t3.sku)
WHERE ((t0.created_at > @p1) AND (t1.sku LIKE CONCAT('%',@p0,'%')))
ORDER BY t0.created_at DESC
-- p0 = [LEFCACP01]
-- p1 = [2015-08-07 16:13:31]
```

I'm also able to use standard .NET controls to perform charting etc.

[image: chart]

I use it for all sorts of database reporting and maintenance activities.

[image: LINQPad]